# How can I mask sensitive data in Application Insights AppRequests table?

Tags: java, azure, azure-application-insights

We are currently facing an issue where AppRequests table in Application Insights is generating sensitive data. We allow customer to access our app via some url (for example, `https://test.com?name=John`). AppRequests table logs this whenever customer is calling our API, with this url in the `Url` column. This url value contains sensitive data and we need to either mask it or delete it.

How can achieve this? I found few answers but it is all related to logs (masking the log we are generating), but AppRequest is generating these entries when url is called.

If I am not understanding how ApplicationInsight correctly, please correct me.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using Workspace-based Application Insights resources, you can apply data collection transformations in Azure Monitor: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/data-collection-transformations

Removing sensitive data is one the primary scenarios why it exists.

You'll be able to use KQL to modify it.